# Como puedo hacer esto

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Estoy creando una especie de blog el cual no lo estoy haciendo con ningún cms ya que estoy midiendo mis capacidades creando uno propio, ya el sistema de esta creado pero me falta solo una cosa, en la base de datos el articulo se guarda en un campo donde se guarda algo así:

```
<h3 style="margin: 15px 0px; padding: 0px; font-weight: 700; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif;">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</h3>
<p style="margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
<p style="text-align: center; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">
<img src="img/imagen.jpg" style="width: 504px; height: 315px;"></p>
<h3 style="margin: 15px 0px; padding: 0px; font-weight: 700; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif;">Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC</h3>
<p style="margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. Neque porro quisquam est, qui dolorem ipsum quia dolor sit amet, consectetur, adipisci velit, sed quia non numquam eius modi tempora incidunt ut labore et dolore magnam aliquam quaerat voluptatem. Ut enim ad minima veniam, quis nostrum exercitationem ullam corporis suscipit laboriosam, nisi ut aliquid ex ea commodi consequatur? Quis autem vel eum iure reprehenderit qui in ea voluptate velit esse quam nihil molestiae consequatur, vel illum qui dolorem eum fugiat quo voluptas nulla pariatur?"</p>
<h3 style="margin: 15px 0px; padding: 0px; font-weight: 700; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif;">1914 translation by H. Rackham</h3>
<p style="margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"</p>
```

Esto es creado con un editor editor wysiwyg, al momento de listar el articulo quiero mostrar el titulo del articulo y la primer imagen que este dentro del articulo, existe la manera de que con php o javascritp (jquery puede ser) el saque la primer etiqueta img completa, es decir del código anterior debería sacar lo siguiente:

```
<img src="img/imagen.jpg" style="width: 504px; height: 315px;">
```

Ya que la primer imagen del articulo seria la imagen ppal del artiuclo y esta apareceria junto con el titulo en el frontend, les agradeceria mucho si me ayudan con alguna idea gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hice este pequeño código, espero te funcione.

```js
var imagen = document.getElementById('imagen');
window.addEventListener('load',function(){

  var parrafos = document.querySelectorAll('p'); //Selecciono todos los parrafos del HTML

  parrafos.forEach(function(hijo){ //los recorro y busco el primer hijo 
  
  if (hijo.childNodes[1] != undefined){ //valido que no sea undifined o sea que tenga un hijo
    console.log(hijo.childNodes[1]);
    imagen.append(hijo.childNodes[1]); //lo agrego a un div solo como ejemplo
  }
  });

});
```

```html
<h3 style="margin: 15px 0px; padding: 0px; font-weight: 700; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif;">The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</h3>
<p style="margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
<p style="text-align: center; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">
<img src="img/imagen.jpg" style="width: 504px; height: 315px;"></p>
<h3 style="margin: 15px 0px; padding: 0px; font-weight: 700; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif;">Section 1.10.32 of "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum", written by Cicero in 45 BC</h3>
<p style="margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">"Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam, eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo. Nemo enim ipsam voluptatem quia voluptas sit aspernatur aut odit aut fugit, sed quia consequuntur magni dolores eos qui ratione voluptatem sequi nesciunt. </p>
<h3 style="margin: 15px 0px; padding: 0px; font-weight: 700; font-size: 14px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif;">1914 translation by H. Rackham</h3>
<p style="margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 15px; margin-left: 0px; padding: 0px; text-align: justify; font-family: &quot;Open Sans&quot;, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;">"But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"</p>

<div id="imagen"></div>
```

Comment: Gracias por aportar voy a ensayar y te comento como me fue. Gracias!!!

Comment: Vale, si te fue de ayuda mi respuesta no olvides darle aceptar (✓) :D